# Phonegap orientation preference depending on screen size

Tags: cordova

I am building a multi-platform app with phonegap. 
On normal and large screen the app is easier to use on landscape but on small devices (i.e. phone or bootstrap extra-small-device) it's easier to use in portrait.

I'd like to know if there is a way to force the orientation depending on the size of the screen using config.xml .
I've looked around the site for answers but i only found specific platform answer. But my app is a web app in HTML5 so i don't have any manifest or plist.

That's why i want to use the config.xml file.

EDIT :

Thanks! I tried the yoik plugin but i can't figure out how to import the plugin. I tried to add:

```
<gap:plugin name="net.yoik.cordova.plugins.screenorientation" />
```

in my config.xml but it didn't seemed to work.

My code is now like this :

```
function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        if (window.outerWidth < 768) {
            screen.lockOrientation('portrait');
            document.location.href = 'www.site.com';
        }
        else {
            screen.lockOrientation('landscape');
            document.location.href = 'www.site.com' ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you are using [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/), right?

Comment: yes and the plugin appeared in the plugin list but my code isn't working.

Comment: Are _screen_ and _screen.lockOrientation_ defined (to check add `alert(typeof screen + " " + typeof screen.lockOrientation)`)? Does the PGB choose the latest version (which is _1.3.2_)? Which platform are you using?

Comment: the alerts don't appeared on my phone and pgb chose 1.3.1 and i tried on ios(7) and android(lollypop). It locks the screen on landscape on tablets but on phone it just set the first orientation as portrait but doesn't lock the rotation. But the document.location.href doesn't work, i always stay on the first page.

Comment: in fact it works on neither of the platform...

Comment: Do you happen to have orientation set in your _config.xml_ already? In that case I suppose you should call `screen.unlockOrientation()` before locking it again.

Comment: no i don't but i'm suspecting the event is never triggered...

Comment: okay so the event was not triggered so i just put the code without any event handling. now the alert work but the lockOrientation function is not defined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68356/discussion-between-sanfor-and-cratein).

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there is a way to do this (at least for all platforms) with just *config.xml*. If you do not necessarily have to use the *config.xml*, you can use [this](https://github.com/yoik/cordova-yoik-screenorientation) handy plugin by yoik. Example of usage of that plugin

```
// set to either landscape
screen.lockOrientation('landscape'); // Or portrait

// allow user rotate
screen.unlockOrientation();
```

Just put the locking into your *deviceReady* event handler with appropriate conditionals to match the screen size requirements.