# How can I restrict the orientation in a cordova android app based on the device?

Tags: cordova

When I use mobile device the orientation should be Portrait.
When I use tablet the orientation should be landscape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this plugin

https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation

and check this issue out.

[Phonegap orientation preference depending on screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797261/phonegap-orientation-preference-depending-on-screen-size)